# Converting gps coords to distance and converting distance to radius in decimal degrees

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps

Based on the GPS coords I get from a user, I want to lookup games within a certain radius (in meters) around the user. I want that radius to be configurable, so it must be passable to a function that converts the specified distance to a radius in decimal degrees.

I store the user GPS coords and the games GPS coords in MongoDB and use the within.center({center: [user.pos[0], user.pos[1]], radius: 1};) query to find games near the position of the user.

The radius property in that query is what I want to make configurable. Let's say I want to convert 50 meters to a radius in decimal degrees:

`convertDistanceToRadiusDegrees('50') -> 0.123`

I then use the result from that function as the value for the radius property.

And I want to calculate the distance between the user and each found game:

`calcDistance(pos1, pos2) -> 50`

Is there a Node.JS module / JS plugin that can do both these functions? So far I've only managed to find Node.JS modules that calculate distance between to points, not convert distance in meters to decimal degrees.

Does a module like that exist? If not, are there any modules that can convert a radius in meters to decimal degrees? Is it even possible?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on how to calculate this, just a Google search away.  Why not write your own module?

Answer (score 0):

One i've been using lately is leafletjs, which full API for GIS calculations.

API - http://leafletjs.com/reference.html

one of the distance methods,

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto

Answer (score 0):

ad "The radius property in that query is what I want to make configurable. Let's say I want to convert 50 meters to a radius in decimal degrees:
convertDistanceToRadiusDegrees('50') -> 0.123
"

This is the wrong way, because 1 °latitude difference is differnet than 1* longitud e difference

Correct is:
Calculate the distance between currentLocation and destination center circle coordinates.
Either use the slow but accurate haversine formula, posted by user melc in the leafletjs API, or search the internet for haverisen formula, its some lines of code, you can copy and paste. There is no need for an addional library.
(The location is inside a circle if its distance to the cneter of the circle is less or equal then the radius)

Tr if you can live with that formula, if you need to check thousnds of destinations per second you need more effort. (e.g an Spatial Index to reduce the calculation sto a few pouints nearby)